# Product rule for Banach space-valued differentiable functions?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded open set and let $f(\cdot,\cdot)$ and $g(\cdot,\cdot)$ be functions from $[0,T]\times \Omega$ into $\mathbb{R}$.

Suppose that $f \in C^1([0,T];H^s(\Omega))$ and $g \in C^1([0,T];H^1(\Omega))$.

The multiplcation $(fg)(t,x) = f(t,x)g(t,x)$ is sensible, and we can consider $(fg)(t) := f(t,\cdot)g(t,\cdot)$ so that $(fg)\colon [0,T] \to L^1(\Omega)$.

Is it true that $fg$ is in $C^1([0,T];L^1(\Omega))$, and does the product rule
$$(fg)'(t) = f'(t)g(t) + f(t)g'(t)$$
hold, in what sense?

Comment: You need $X=Y=A$, where $A$ is a banach algebra  for this makes sense. Please modify your question

Comment: Really? I can't have $X=H^1$ and $Y=C^1(\overline{\Omega})$?

Comment: I think no, because you need the same range space for both products $f\cdot g$ and $g\cdot f$

Comment: Hmm. I thought one could consider $(fg)(t) = f(t,\cdot)g(t,\cdot)$  so $fg\colon [0,T] \to Z$ for some Banach space $Z$. Then $fg$ can be differentiated by using the limit

Comment: Then you need to say that you have multiplication of vectors of $X$ and $Y$ with values $Z$. But this is very bad multiplication because for example $f\cdot g\cdot h$ makes no sense here. The most reasonable assumption is written in the first comment

Comment: @Norbert Thanks for your comments. Please see my edit. I agree your assumption is most reasonable but I do not have Banach algebra ($H^1 \subset H^s$ but $H^s$ is not Banach algebra unless the dimension is good)